# CSS3 media queries to target specific device

Tags: wordpress, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have my wordpress theme with basic CCS, Now I want to make this design responsive for  most used device layout's noted below.And I want to target all apple devices in landscape as well as in portrait mode:-

```
blackberry(320x240),
iphone3 (320x480),
iphone4 (640x960),
iphone5 (640x1136),
ipad    (1024x768),
large desktop screen above 1280.
```

How can I write my CSS stylesheet using CSS3 media queries to target responsive devices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/
Here is just a starter. You can read more abour media-queries and other resonsive design stuff on that blog.

Here is a sample of css code:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```